# How to compare Javascript date objects generated by differently formatted date strings?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have 2 javascript date objects generated by ISO strings of slightly different formats coming from 2 different external APIs.

Both do not have timezone information. How can I ensure that they match in cases such as this -

```
let d1 = new Date("2020-05-23T00:00:00.000Z");
console.log(d1.toDateString())

let d2 = new Date("2020-05-23T00:00:00");
console.log(d2.toDateString())

if (d1.getTime() === d2.getTime()) {
  console.log("It's a match!");
}
```

Output -

```
[LOG]: Sat May 23 2020 
[LOG]: Sat May 23 2020
```

Comment: They are not the same, that's why the time is different. Z means "zero offset".

Comment: @Aleksey - So does that mean d2 doesn't have a zero offset by virtue of not having any TZ info? In that case how do I set d2 to also have a zero offset?

Comment: First question would be what time zone your apis are using? is it always UTC just without providing this info or is it a fixed time zone or depends the time zone on something like a user account? JS will always use the browsers time zone setting when parsing dates without time zone offset. If your want UTC, you could simply add "Z" at the end of your string. if you need more advanced time zone support, take a look at https://momentjs.com/

Comment: You can't really, the one source is telling you with a greater degree of accuracy than the other. What you could do is to check `d1.getTime() - d2.getTime() < X` where you set X to meet whatever ms requirement you want. If you set `X` to 86400000 it's gonna be 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Date.parse()` to see the times in milliseconds, and then you can compare equality. By JavaScript methods the two datetime values are different:

```js
let d1 = new Date("2020-05-23T00:00:00.000Z");
console.log(d1.toDateString())

let d2 = new Date("2020-05-23T00:00:00");
console.log(d2.toDateString())

console.log('parsed dates:', Date.parse(d1), Date.parse(d2))

if (d1.getTime() === d2.getTime()) {
  console.log("It's a match!");
}
```

More on `Date.parse()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse